# Manhua where the main female character is a fox who needs to find her tails. She gets caught and kept as a pet

Tags: story-identification, manga

I need help finding a manhua where the female lead is a fox. She needs to find her tails. She gets caught by the male lead and kept as his pet. She needs to find her tails which are on people that need her help, so she escapes him constantly. Only after helping them can she get her tail.

I'm pretty sure that it's a cultivation manhua.

Comment: Lotsa foxy manga and manhua listed here; [Any manga/manhua/manhwa featuring a 9 tailed fox, or a fox spirit also works?](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/h98clu/any_mangamanhuamanhwa_featuring_a_9_tailed_fox_or/)

Comment: https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/who-touched-my-tail-novel kind of matches, but it's a webnovel only, and the main character is male.